# call-process and Hunspell (in Emacs 24.4)

Tags: eshell, microsoft-windows, shell-command, ispell

I am having problems running [ezwinports Hunspell 1.3.2-3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files) in Emacs 24.4.1 for  Windows.

When calling `ispell-buffer` with debug, I see the following functions are called.

`ispell-buffer` -> `ispell-region` -> `ispell-set-spellchecker-params` -> `ispell-find-aspell-dictionaries` ->

```
(ispell-call-process ispell-program-name null-device t nil "-D")
```

which in turn will become:

```
(call-process "c:/path/to/bin/hunspell.exe" "NUL" t nil "-D")
```

This function returns this error, which eventually prevents the spell checking (actual `c:\path\to\` is longer):

```
SEARCH PATH:
.;;C:\Hunspell\;C:\Users\admin\.openoffice.org\3\user\wordbook;c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.4\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.3\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.2\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.1\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.0\share\dict\ooo\
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\default
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\en_GB
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\en_US
Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "ENG".
```

The strange is that running from Windows prompt (terminal):

```
c:\path\to\bin\hunspell.exe -D
```

one gets (without errors):

```
SEARCH PATH:
.;;C:\Hunspell\;C:\Users\admin\.openoffice.org\3\user\wordbook;c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.4\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.3\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.2\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.1\share\dict\ooo\;C:\Program files\OpenOffice.org 2.0\share\dict\ooo\
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\default
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\en_GB
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\en_US
LOADED DICTIONARY:
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\default.aff
c:\path\to\bin\..\share\hunspell\default.dic
Hunspell 1.3.2
```

Testing separately:

```
(call-process "c:/path/to/bin/hunspell.exe" "NUL" t nil)
```

it gives:

```
Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "ENG".
```

While from the prompt:

```
c:\path\to\bin\hunspell.exe
```

starts the spelling.

Emacs errors can be replicated using `eshell` mode, which is perhaps based on `call-process`.

Noted that this works as expected:

```
(call-process "c:/path/to/bin/hunspell.exe" "NUL" t nil "-vv")
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.3.2)
```

I tried with other commands to replicate the call-process error. But, whenever I run   `(call-process "c:/path/to/foo.exe" "NUL" t nil "some args")`, the result is always the same as 
`c:/path/to/foo.exe some args` from the terminal.

It should be noted that the code in `ispell-set-spellchecker-params`
is run only at the first ispell invocation, so on a second spell-checking request the action can be completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having this problem. It seems that hunspell picks up the language to use for spell-checking from the `LANG` environmental variable. It appears that the variable is set to 'ENG' in your emacs. What hunspell is saying is that it cannot find dictionaries associated with that language.

You have two options either download the dictionaries that language or set the `LANG` environment variable to something for which hunspell already has the dictionaries for.

I went with the second option and explicitly set the variable to `en_US` on windows

```
(when (equal system-type 'windows-nt)
  (setenv "LANG" "en_US"))
```

Comment: Wow actually I had realised it might have been something connected with env vars. So I used `Set` in Windows CLI and found nothing relevant and started Emacs with `-q` to neutralise init settings. Now I wonder where this variable comes from.

Comment: I found the answer in the manual: "On MS-Windows, if LANG is not already set in the environment when Emacs starts, Emacs sets it based on the system-wide default language, which you can set in the ‘Regional Settings’ Control Panel on some versions of MS-Windows."

Comment: Gah! I've been fighting with this for ages and this is the solution! If I set LANG I don't even need to tell emacs 24.5 to use hunspell, it all just works automagically! Brilliant!

Comment: I've had a long back and forth with Eli Zaretskii of ezwinports and it seems that setting LANG could potentially affect emacs or other applications in unexpected way. It's probably better to set the DICTIONARY environment variable to the name of your dictionary. Alternately just copy the dictionary files you want to ENG.dic and ENG.aff. Even if they're Norwegian that will work.